# Linkbutton inside a gridview not firing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvBlockUnblock" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                       BackColor ="AliceBlue"
                      onrowdatabound="gvBlockUnblock_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="CPID,PUBLISHED"
                    style="margin-top: 0px" 
                    AllowPaging="True" onpageindexchanging="gvBlockUnblock_PageIndexChanging" 
                    PageSize="10" EnableViewState= "true"
                    onselectedindexchanged="gvBlockUnblock_SelectedIndexChanged" >

        <Columns>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.No.">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbSNo" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# (Eval("sno")) %>'
                    PostBackUrl='<%#"~/_UILayer/ComplaintReport.aspx?PINo="+Eval("CPID") %>' >
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:BoundField  HeaderText = "Complaint" />

         <asp:HyperLinkField   DataNavigateUrlFields="CPID" datatextfield = "CPID"
                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="WebForm1.aspx?CPID={0}" HeaderText=" Problem Item No"/>


            <asp:BoundField  DataField="NewComplaints" 
                HeaderText="Number of New Complaints" SortExpression="NewComplaints" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalNumberofComplaints" 
                HeaderText="Total Number of Complaints" SortExpression="TotalNumberofComplaints" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NumberofUnblocks" HeaderText="Number of Unblocks" 
                SortExpression="TotalNumberofComplaints" />



          <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText = "Comments">
           <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdminComment" Font-Names="Arial" ReadOnly="false" Width="200" Height="30"
                            TextMode="multiLine" runat="server" BorderStyle="NotSet"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


           <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText = " Block / Unblock">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:button ID ="btnBlockUnblock"  runat = "server" 
                         Text = '<%# CheckBlock(Eval("PUBLISHED")) %>' CommandName="Select" 
                        CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"  CausesValidation="False"  />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>



                    <asp:HyperLinkField   DataNavigateUrlFields="CPID"  Text="View Details"  
                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="ItemHistoryForm.aspx?CPID={0}" HeaderText=" Problem Item No"/>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

aspx.cs

```
   protected void gvBlockUnblock_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ComplaintProfileId = gvBlockUnblock.DataKeys[gvBlockUnblock.SelectedIndex].Values["CPID"].ToString();
        string ISPUBLISHED = gvBlockUnblock.DataKeys[gvBlockUnblock.SelectedIndex].Values["PUBLISHED"].ToString();

        string date = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)gvBlockUnblock.Rows[gvBlockUnblock.SelectedIndex].FindControl("txtAdminComment");
        string Comment = tb.Text;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Comment))
        {

            WebMsgBox.Show("empty");
        }
        else
        {
            if (ISPUBLISHED == "N")
            {
                ISPUBLISHED = "N";
            }
            else
            {
                ISPUBLISHED = "Y";
            }
            string AdminComment = (System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " :  " + Comment);

            AddCommentBLL.InsertComment(AdminComment, ComplaintProfileId, ISPUBLISHED);
            gvBlockUnblock.DataSource = AddCommentBLL.GetItem();
            gvBlockUnblock.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

So, on click of the button ID ="btnBlockUnblock", this grid view selectedindex changed needs to fire. The page is refreshing though.

Thanks
Sun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the GridView `RowCommand` event instead of the GridView `SelectedIndex` Change..  e.g

```
protected void gvBlockUnblock_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {

string ComplaintProfileId = gvBlockUnblock.DataKeys[gvBlockUnblock.SelectedIndex].Values["CPID"].ToString();
    string ISPUBLISHED = gvBlockUnblock.DataKeys[gvBlockUnblock.SelectedIndex].Values["PUBLISHED"].ToString();

    string date = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)gvBlockUnblock.Rows[gvBlockUnblock.SelectedIndex].FindControl("txtAdminComment");
    string Comment = tb.Text;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Comment))
    {

        WebMsgBox.Show("empty");
    }
    else
    {
        if (ISPUBLISHED == "N")
        {
            ISPUBLISHED = "N";
        }
        else
        {
            ISPUBLISHED = "Y";
        }
        string AdminComment = (System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " :  " + Comment);

        AddCommentBLL.InsertComment(AdminComment, ComplaintProfileId, ISPUBLISHED);
        gvBlockUnblock.DataSource = AddCommentBLL.GetItem();
        gvBlockUnblock.DataBind();
    }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** After reading code from your comment, I found your problem.

What happens actually, when you click the button, the Page Load event fires before your gridview event and there your gridview data again binded and it lost your `fired event`. You have to examine your page Postback by putting `if(!IsPostBack)` in your page load where you are trying to bind your data to gridview.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     if(!IsPostBack)
     {
        // gets the items table using stored proc GetItem
        gvBlockUnblock.DataSource = AddCommentBLL.GetItem();
        gvBlockUnblock.DataBind();
        // used for paging
        Session["MyDataSett"] = gvBlockUnblock.DataSource;
     }
   }
```

Comment: protected void gvBlockUnblock_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        
I tried the code in OnRowCommand, 
            if (e.CommandName == "Select"). Still no use