# RowCommand not firing when clicking buttons inside TemplateField

Tags: asp.net

Basically I have a GridView:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="gvServices" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
                      ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowSorting="True" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="gvServices_RowCommand">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
```

And inside I have 2 TemplateFields:

```
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnStart" runat="server" Text="Start" CommandName="StartService" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnStop" runat="server" Text="Stop" CommandName="StopService" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Finally I have the method thats supposed to fire when clicking on either of the Buttons on the gridView, problem is that when I click either of them the event does not get called at all

```
    public void gvServices_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        if (e.CommandName == "StartService")
        {
            StartServiceItem(gvServices.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text, locations[index]);
        }
        if (e.CommandName == "StopService")
        {
            StopServiceItem(gvServices.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text, locations[index]);
        }
        loadGridView();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

RowCommand on GridView does fire from a button within a TemplateField. Check out the answer to this thread:

[Linkbutton inside a gridview not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736491/linkbutton-inside-a-gridview-not-firing)

Answer (score 4):

You need to listen to the buttons `RowCommand`. [GridView.RowCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) is used when you have an `asp:ButtonField` on each row.

Aspx code:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnStart" runat="server" Text="Start" OnCommand="GridButtons_Command" CommandName="StartService" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnStop" runat="server" Text="Stop" OnCommand="GridButtons_Command" CommandName="StopService" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code Behind:

```
public void GridButtons_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    if (e.CommandName == "StartService")
    {
        StartServiceItem(gvServices.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text, locations[index]);
    }
    if (e.CommandName == "StopService")
    {
        StopServiceItem(gvServices.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text, locations[index]);
    }
    loadGridView();
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution! Thanks :)